# Django FilterSet set initial value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-template-filters

We are using Django_Filterset in our project. I have been asked to set a default filter value for a foreign key column in the model

```
class RegFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Reg
        fields = {
          'id': ['exact'],
          'nom_id': ['icontains'],
          'nom_name': ['icontains'],
          'product__name': ['icontains']
        }
```

The product name should default to a product already in the db when the initial screen is displayed - any idea how this can be achieved? Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can add `default` value in `models`, that would help while creation of the object. I think that doesn't require any `FilterSet` class

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge - I have tried that, no joy.

Comment: What is your current status of your requirement?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge - We need to set an initial value for product name so that's the default query result. I am not sure how to set a default product name in the filter set.

Comment: As far I understood, whenever someone accesses your REST-API, it should return a queryset/some results that are already filtered with some conditions. Right?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge - Correct. I had to find the right one that did the job for me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built on the answer given by @Gayathri and fixed a few small issues. He had a typo in his code, and the code wouldn't work with multiple choice fields, since they require the `MultiValueDict` functionality for multiple entries.

Given a rather regular view, here is the full code (in Python3 syntax):

```
class BookListView(FilterView):
    model = Book
    filterset_class = BookFilter

    def get_filterset_kwargs(self, filterset_class):
        kwargs = super().get_filterset_kwargs(filterset_class)
        if kwargs['data'] is None:
            filter_values = MultiValueDict()
        else:
            filter_values = kwargs['data'].copy()

        if not filter_values:
            # we need to use `setlist` for multi-valued fields to emulate this coming from a query dict
            filter_values.setlist('status', ['new', 'ready'])
            filter_values['sorting'] = '-created'

        kwargs['data'] = filter_values

        return kwargs
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this one and thought the solution might help someone else in a situation similar to me.

In the views.py, override the FilterView method

```
def get_filterset_kwargs(self, filterset_class):
    kwargs = super(RegFilter, self).get_filterset_kwargs(filterset_class)
    if kwargs['data'] is None:
        request_dict = {}
    else:
        request_dict = kwargs['data'].dict()

    # This default will not be populated if any other filter options are chosen to restrict the query set
    if not request_dict:
        request_dict.update({
            'product__name': 'ABC Product'
        })

    request_dict = kwargs['data']

    return kwargs
```

This should now set the default product as 'ABC product' when no other options are passed to restrict the data fetched.

Comment: Can you please post your view

Comment: There are small issues with this code. Please see my answer for an updated version.

Comment: Use `kwargs['data'] = request_dict` instead. Problem solved.