# How to add a default filter inside Django FilterSet?

Tags: python, django, filter, overriding, django-filter

**The Problem:**

I am trying to add an **initial filter** that gives a base queryset for other filters to further filter on.

**Things I've Tried:**

- I tried overriding the `qs` property method, but overriding the `qs` made other filters unfunctional.
- I also tried to override the `__init__` method but it was not called in my custom filter class.

Comment: Share your code too

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the **init** method of your custom FilterSet class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourCustomFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.form.initial['your_field'] = "default_value"
```

Do not forget to mention this in your View class:

```
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
filterset_class = YourCustomFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

A FilterSet takes a queryset as an argument, so you can just filter your own queryset, then pass it in:

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
my_filters = MyFilterSetClass(queryset=queryset)
```

If you're using a FilterView, you can just set the view queryset (or use get_queryset()):

```py
class MyFilterView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = MyFilterSetClass
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48564794/7359776), with the second last line of code corrected to `kwargs['data'] = request_dict`. It works for me.